# Improper behavior for command dnx Run & dnx web

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have created a simple WEB API application using Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 14.04(on my VMWare). I completed all prior steps to install & configure .NET core, VS Code (V 1.0.0) & mono libraries and packages. my `package.json` file contains following parameter as:

`"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
}`

when I use 'ctrl+shift+p' to get command pallet, I can get `dnx:Run Command`, however after selecting this, I am not getting `dnx web - (MyApplication)`. When I tried to run same application from terminal using `dnx web`. I am getting proper results of saying :

`Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.`

Same application, I moved to my windows 7 environment, I am getting everything expected from VS Code. I don't have to run explicitly from command prompt.

Is it the behavior of VS Code on **Ubuntu** Vs **Windows** environment or something is wrong.

Comment: I'm going to try to setup DNX and OmniSharp again. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'll post if I have any success.

Comment: At this point I'm getting dnx: Run Command and dnx: Web  (HelloWeb) for my sample app after clicking dnx: Run. However clicking dnx: Web does nothing while dnx web from terminal runs the server as you mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new open issue with OmniSharp regarding this:

['dnx web' doesn't execute in VSCode 1.0.0 on OpenSuSe Leap 42.1 #215](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-server/issues/215)

You may want to keep track of it.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I asked raised same issue on GitHub on VS Code, however it is redirected to OmniSharp. [Here is the link](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-server/issues/214)

Comment: GJSmith3rd, did you come across any solution, by any chance?